# How to properly map joined models to DTO's?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a struggle that I can't seem to get out of. I am making a simple Web API in C# ASP.NET and I came across the following problem:

I want to do joined queries on the database, but this will introduce new fields that my current model does not have (and thus cant map).

Lets say this is the 1st model:

```
public class Artefact
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public Guid Completed_By { get; set; }
    public DateTime Completed_At { get; set; }
    public Guid PhaseId { get; set; }
    public int DefaultArtefactId { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the second model:

```
public class DefaultArtefact
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Artefact_Type { get; set; }

    public string Phase { get; set; }
}
```

The function:

```
   public async Task<IEnumerable<Artefact>> GetArtefactsFromProject(Guid projectId)
    {
        const string query = @"SELECT a.Id, a.Status, a.Completed_By, a.Completed_At, da.Name AS DefaultArtefactName, da.Artefact_Type FROM artefact a JOIN defaultartefacts da ON a.DefaultArtefactId = da.Id
                                JOIN Phase ph ON a.PhaseId = ph.Id JOIN Project p ON ph.ProjectId = p.Id WHERE p.Id = @ProjectId";
        using var connection = CreateConnection();
        return await connection.QueryAsync<Artefact>(query, new { ProjectId = projectId});
    }
```

The models map 1 on 1 to the database tables. Now I want a joined statement so that I can get the defaultartefact name along with the artefact information.

**My Problem:**

The problem that I am facing is that when I do the joined statement, it can't map to one of these models since the models do not contain fields for the rows that are in the other model (artefact does not contain a field DefaultArtefactName and thus can't map that information).

Should I make a new model for each joined statement then **or**
use already existing methods in the DAL to first iterate through the artefacts, use the Id to get the name and map it in the business logic layer to a new DTO which does contain these fields?

The models map 1 on 1 to the database tables. Now I want a joined statement so that I can get the defaultartefact name along with the artefact information.

**My Problem:**

The problem that I am facing is that when I do the joined statement, it can't map to one of these models since the models do not contain fields for the rows that are in the other model (artefact does not contain a field DefaultArtefactName and thus can't map that information).

Should I make a new model for each joined statement then **or**
use already existing methods in the DAL to first iterate through the artefacts, use the Id to get the name and map it in the business logic layer to a new DTO which does contain these fields?

Comment: > The models map 1 on 1 to the database tables. 

There is NO reason for that. My API mdoels, i.e., generally use a GUID as key - in the database this is a secondary unique field with an Identity counte as primary key for performance reasons.

Comment: Are you doing that manually or has someone enlightened you on the use of Automapper to map IQueryable and transform between representations automatically?

Comment: Please add some code so we know exactly what you're doing or want to do because this leaves me with a lot of guesses.

Comment: @TomTom, I added the code. I use Dapper to map, but it is more a general question. Do you make a new model and DTO for each joined statement or do you use the already existing DAL methods to map the data?

Answer (score 0):

From your code, you are using Dapper to fetch data with relationships. Dapper provides the [Relationship](https://www.learndapper.com/relationships#dapper-relationships) feature to map multiple objects with its nested object.

1. Add `DefaultArtefact` property in the `Artefact` class.

```cs
public class Artefact
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public Guid Completed_By { get; set; }
    public DateTime Completed_At { get; set; }
    public Guid PhaseId { get; set; }
    public int DefaultArtefactId { get; set; }
    public DefaultArtefact DefaultArtefact { get; set; }
}
```

2. Modify the query and query the `Artfeact` object with nested `DefaultArtefact` object with [`splitOn`](https://www.learndapper.com/relationships#dapper-spliton).

```cs
public async Task<IEnumerable<Artefact>> GetArtefactsFromProject(Guid projectId)
{
    const string query = @"SELECT a.Id, a.Status, a.Completed_By, a.Completed_At,  
            a.DefaultArtefactId, da.Name, da.Artefact_Type 
        FROM artefact a 
        JOIN defaultartefacts da ON a.DefaultArtefactId = da.Id               
        JOIN Phase ph ON a.PhaseId = ph.Id 
        JOIN Project p ON ph.ProjectId = p.Id 
        WHERE p.Id = @ProjectId";

    using var connection = CreateConnection();
        
    return await connection.QueryAsync<Artefact, DefaultArtefact, Artefact>(
        new CommandDefinition(query, new { ProjectId = projectId }), 
        map: (artefact, defaultArtefact) => {
            artefact.DefaultArtefact = defaultArtefact;
            return artefact;
        }, 
        splitOn: "DefaultArtefactId");
}
```

Comment: So I have to add a new field to my Artefact model just so that I can do 1 join query?
And then I have to edit all the other methods that use the Artefact model to match this new model?

Comment: It depends on your use case. If currently your `Artefact` model has other dependencies, I would suggest you create a new model. As you said *edit all the other methods that use the Artefact model to match this new model*, this is highly risky if you use the current model that will affect to other part, you have to retest to ensure that the change doesn't break the other.